# How to know the number of messages received in a message queue at a point of time

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have a implementation where the hardware dispatches 300 packets every second to a host application through DMA transfer and then to the host application's message queue.

When packets are sent at high rate to the app, I see that the app is not receiving one or two packets like this. When I use `tcpdump`, I see that all packets are posted to the host. But how do i know whether where the packet was dropped? Using debug prints will consume CPU usage and not be easy as well.

Can I find out how many messages that I received on that message queue? Using `ipcs -q commmand` does not list anything.

Answer (score 1):

SysV messages queues are small by default, on my system `ipcs -l` displays:

```
$ ipcs -l
[...]
------ Messages: Limits --------
max queues system wide = 7890
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384
```

The corresponding sysctl entries being:

```
kernel.msgmni = 7890
kernel.msgmax = 8192
kernel.msgmnb = 16384
```

Depending on how big the messages are, you might hit some of these limits.